# Matlab - Generating random coordinates for a matrix

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, coordinates, permutation

I need to create a list (of size n) of random, non-repeating set of coordinates on a matrix of predefined size.

Is there a fast way to generate this in Matlab?

My initial idea was to create a list of size n with permutations the size of (width x length) and to translate them back to Row and Col values, but it seems to me too much.

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: What happens if `n` is greater than the number of elements in the matrix? Are repeats acceptable then?

Comment: I've uploaded the project to git: https://github.com/guywald/allele_fixation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `randperm` to generate a linear index, and convert it to [row,col] if needed using `ind2sub`.

```
x = rand(7,9);
n = 20;
ndx = randperm(numel(x), n);
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(x), ndx);
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as `n` is less than the number of elements in the matrix this is simple:

```
% A is the matrix to be sampled
% N is the number of coordinate pairs you want
numInMat = numel(A);

% sample from 1:N without replacement
ind = randperm(numInMat, N);

% convert ind to Row,Col pairs
[r, c] = ind2sub( size(A), ind )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is a good one, although you don't even have to convert your linear indices back to row and col indices, you can do linear indexing directly into a 2D array.

```
idx = randperm(prod(size(data)))
```

where data is your matrix. This will generate a vector of random integers between 1 and `prod(size(data))`, i.e. one index for each element.

e.g.

```
n = 3;
data = magic(n);
idx = randperm(prod(size(data)));
reshape(data(idx), size(data)) %this gives you your randomly indexed data matrix back
```

Comment: `although you don't even have to convert your linear indices back to row and col indices`, well the OP specifically asked for a way to generate coordinates, not linear indices

Comment: @slayton I suppose you're right, I had figured that the OP was just looking for an indexing scheme as opposed to trying to generate coordinates for some other purpose. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: meh, its not a bad answer i'd keep it